# Firebase only authenticating on some devices?

Tags: android, algorithm, security, firebase, authentication

I have tested this on my Moto G5+ (works) and Nexus 6 (doesn't work), and my firebase authentication only works on one of them:

```
  mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); 

            if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) { //No existing user
                mAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.v("myTag", "Cannot authenticate user" + e);
                    }
                });
            } 
            if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                Log.v("myTag", "Boutta take photos");

                takePhoto(this, 0);//back camera
            }else{
                Log.v("myTag", "Cannot take photos, user not authenticated");
            }
```

**What's odd is that I only get the log `Cannot take photos, the user not authenticated`, but not the log `Cannot authenticate user`. This means I am able to authenticate the user, but for some reason, it does not work**

How come this only works on some devices?

Comment: Is the Nexus 6 on the emulator?

Comment: @martinomburajr No, it's real

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your user starts off unauthenticated, once the first `if` statement is called and it attempts the anonymous sign in, that anonymous sign in happens asynchronously as it is waiting on a callback. So in that state the user isn't authenticated until the call back completes. The code then jumps to your second set of if/else statements where you check

```
mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null
```

but the callback for authentication still may have not returned, and your `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` is still null therefore jumping to the else statement and logging the  `Log.v("myTag", "Cannot take photos, user not authenticated");`

Your callback may then return authenticating the user but at this point, its too late. You already run logic assuming the use wasn't authenticated.

Comment: You are so right! Thank you so much, I really appreciate it! +1

Comment: No problem, I make that Async problem all the time. Also I would recommend using the different callbacks i.e onComplete, onSuccess etc as you have done to then branch my code appropriately

Answer (score 0):

@martinomburajr brought me to the right answer! Just to elaborate on his solution, in case anyone else has the same problem in the future, I needed to wait until the authentication was successful:

```
           mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

                if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) { //No existing user
                    Log.v("myTag", "Boutta authenticate");
                    mAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        }
                    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

//TAKE PHOTO HERE INSTEAD
                    takePhoto(c, 0);//back camera


                            }else{
                                Log.v("myTag", "Cannot take photos, user not authenticated");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else {
                    Log.v("myTag", "aalready authenticated!");

                    takePhoto(c, 0);//back camera
                    frontOrBack = 0;
                }


            }
```

When I put my authentication-dependent code (in this case, to take a picture) I wasn't giving my app enough time to get a response from Firebase. Instead of just assuming that the user was authenticated, however, I fixed this issue by putting the authentication-dependent code in an `OnCompleteListener`. Many thanks to @martinomburajr for his helpful answer!